# Dialogflow CX webhook for fulfilment to reply user using nodejs

Tags: node.js, webhooks, dialogflow-cx

I tried using dialogflow-fulfillment library but I guess it is for Dialogflow ES so now I am using
@google-cloud/dialogflow-cx library but I don't know how to use this library for webhook connection to reply to users using fulfilments, there is very little material available for Dialogflow CX.

````
// use credentials or keyFilename i'm using keyFile
    credentials: {
        private_key: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
 
        client_email:"pro1a3711.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    },                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        keyFilename: './pr.json'
}

const {SessionsClient} = require('@google-cloud/dialogflow-cx');
const projectId = 'pro1-293711';
const location = 'global';
const agentId = 'da2271f5-0221-4dce-98d3-efa----9dd';
const languageCode = 'en';
 const query = ['hello'];
// Imports the Google Cloud Some API library
//console.log(WebhooksClient)
const client = new SessionsClient(config);
   //console.log("client",client)
     async function detectIntentText() {
        const sessionId = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
    const sessionPath = client.projectLocationAgentSessionPath(
      projectId,
      location,
      agentId,
      sessionId
    );
    console.info(sessionPath);
    const request = {
        session: sessionPath,
        queryInput: {
          text: {
            text: query,
          },
          languageCode,
        },
      };
      const [response] = await client.detectIntent(request);
      console.log(`User Query: ${query}`);
      for (const message of response.queryResult.responseMessages) {
        if (message.text) {
          console.log(`Agent Response: ${message.text.text}`);
        }
      }
      if (response.queryResult.match.intent) {
        console.log(
          `Matched Intent: ${response.queryResult.match.intent.displayName}`
        );
      }
      console.log(
        `Current Page: ${response.queryResult.currentPage.displayName}`
      );
    }

 detectIntentText()```
````

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that the [dialogflow-fulfillment](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs) library only supports [Dialogflow ES](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs) and the [@google-cloud/dialogflow-cx](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow-cx) library is only used for node.js applications to access [Dialogflow CX](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs) [API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3beta1-overview).

As there are no fulfillment libraries available yet for Dialogflow CX, you can refer to the Dialogflow CX [webhook request](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3beta1#webhookrequest) and [webhook response](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3beta1#webhookresponse) for building webhook services for your Dialogflow CX agent.

You can also refer to the sample webhook service code for Dialogflow CX using Node.js and [express](https://expressjs.com/) below:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post("/webhook", (request, response) => {
  let tag = request.body.fulfillmentInfo.tag;
  let jsonResponse = {};
  if (tag == "welcome tag") {
    //fulfillment response to be sent to the agent if the request tag is equal to "welcome tag"
    jsonResponse = {
      fulfillment_response: {
        messages: [
          {
            text: {
              //fulfillment text response to be sent to the agent
              text: ["Hi! This is a webhook response"]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  } else {
    jsonResponse = {
      //fulfillment text response to be sent to the agent if there are no defined responses for the specified tag
      fulfillment_response: {
        messages: [
          {
            text: {
              ////fulfillment text response to be sent to the agent
              text: [
                `There are no fulfillment responses defined for "${tag}"" tag`
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  }
  response.json(jsonResponse);
});

const listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log("Your app is listening on port " + listener.address().port);
});
```

Comment: Still looks like the situation hasn't changed, even after about 1.5 years

Comment: @Marc Do you have any idea about how to send images as well in the message using url of the image?